# Android ListView summary

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using a ListActivity in the usual way: load an ArrayList of `Item` from the database and use a custom adapter to show the data.
I display my ListView like this (each row is an `Item`):

```
  Date      Field1   Field2  ... Fieldn
2012/03/02   ...       ...         ...
2012/03/02   ...       ...         ...
2012/03/02   ...       ...         ...
2012/04/07   ...       ...         ...
```

What I want to do is show a row summary grouping by date. For example, I want to display the previous list like the next one:

```
  Date      Field1   Field2  ... Fieldn
** 2012/03/02 3 rows
2012/03/02   ...       ...         ...
2012/03/02   ...       ...         ...
2012/03/02   ...       ...         ...
** 2012/04/07 1 row
2012/04/07   ...       ...         ...
```

So, my question is how I can do it? I need to implement my own ListView? or there is a feature of ListView that I don't know yet?

Comment: i think you might looking for [ExpandableView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), take a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ExpandableListView` instead, with "** 2012/03/02 3 rows" and "** 2012/04/07 1 row" are the parent items and the rest are children items. Here is the place you can look up: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about ExpandableListView.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use android-section-list

The header of top section is sticky at the top of the list. It is similar to sectioned list from iOS

https://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/

[image]